# How to use azure cognitive translation services with android?

Tags: android, azure, translate, azure-cognitive-services

I want to build a text translator using azure cognitive services but i don't know how to use it in the android.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [`SDK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-translate-speech-java-jre) and then call like below

```
 try {
      translatedText = Translate.execute(sentence, baseLanguage, targetLanguage);
      return true;
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
 }
```

Comment: and what about api key and all please provide full code with rest API JSON response

Comment: everything is there in the link i added abov

Comment: this is for eclipse not android studio

Comment: @AshishSharma, Stack Overflow is not the place where we will build all the code for you. Please have a look to "how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am stuck at one place I have to send the response in json format and i don't know how to do it.